# ssdt 14.0.60329 Failed to load the package "Exception deserializing..."Could not load type... IDTSSupportTargetServerVersion130'

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

I installed RC2 for SQL 2016 on our database server.  Seems to work well.  So I tried to install the latest SSDT 14.0.60329 on my workstation. Win10, VS2015 update 1.

First I had this problem:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2503095

It was fixed by installing:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/05/ssdt-preview-update-rc2/

But now I get the new message:
ssdt 14.0.60329 Failed to load the package "Exception deserializing the package "Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSSupportTargetServerVersion130' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91

I uninstalled SSMS and SSDT.

I installed VS2015 update 2 then reinstalled the latest SSDT and still get the same error.

Any ideas?  I search for this error and get 0 results from google.

Comment: is it throwing this error on startup, package validation, or execution?  Are you able to connect with SSMS? Where did you get your Copy of SSDT? Where did you get your copy of SSMS? Is this issue local to you or are your coworkers having the same issue?

Comment: Error is on start (debug).  Connection to SQL is fine from any tool or code.  See my post about where I got ssdt rc2.  I am the only one testing the new installs at my company and so the only one having the issue.

Comment: After uninstalling all versions of SQL Server and SSMS from my PC I was able to install SSDT 14.0.5112 and everything is working fine so far.  I would like to use the RC2 version though.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Rogier No I did not.  2016 should release soon, so I will just stay put until then.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by changing the TargetServerVersion from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2014, which is what I need anyway.

1. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer
2. Go to Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General and change the TargetServerVersion there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This helped me solve a different issue but was not the problem in this case.  Now that I am on VS update2 and the newest SSDT there are no longer any issues.